# How to make a letter appear in italics while within \ce?

Tags: chemistry

I'm trying to type the following equation:

[image: Desired output]

In LaTeX, I can recreate this as follows:

```
\ce{Rate = k[A]^m[B]^n ...}
```

Which comes out as

[image: Actual output]

But I would like for the k to be in italics, similar to how it would be if it were not within \ce{}. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: `\ce` is the wrong tool. This is a mathematical expression, not a chemical formula.

Comment: @SandyG This is the best working example that I think I can provide. I'm working using notion, where I use the integrated /math command to put in basic LaTeX strings. It doesn't support \documentclass or \usepackage.

Comment: Can you just use `$\text{Rate}=k[A]^m[B]^n\dots$` (without `\ce`)?

Comment: @SandyG possibly with `\ce{A}` and `\ce{B}` as they represent chemical substances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you are using the `mhchem` package very creatively, you could use this option:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
    
    \ce{Rate = \text{\textit{k}}[A]^m[B]^n \ldots}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: rate constant]

This way you use the `\ce{}` command as a shortcut for mathematical environments, but who cares ...

Comment: Mind you: despite the answer I still strongly agree with cgnieder. The package is developed to be use for type setting chemical compound formula, not for displaying mathematical formules even when they are chemistry related.